# Input a JSON variable to python -mjson.tool

Tags: python, json, bash, curl

So in order to parse a JSON with bash, I use python -mjson.tool to grep the field and awk to get the value. I used to pipe it right after curl, so I could do something like `curl $url | python -mjson.tool | grep (something) | awk (something)` But I want to store the curl output to a variable and send that to the python -mjson.tool. I tried `python -mjson.tool $json` or `python -mjson.tool <<< $json` but neither has worked. Is there a way to feed in a json variable to python?

Also, I cannot use jq.

Comment: The second attempt there should have worked though quoting the variable expansion *might* make a difference (and you should always do that anyway). That being said you effectively **never** need `grep | awk` in a pipeline as awk can do just about (if not actually) everything `grep` can do and for this sort of thing it is probably better to just use python directly anyway.

Comment: Can you expand more on not using grep? I figured it's more readable if I `grep` a field.

Comment: awk can search for lines with given text itself. `/foo/ {<awk commands here only happen on lines that match 'foo'}` for example.

Comment: There's also an awesome tool called [jsawk](https://github.com/micha/jsawk) which might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, you need to quote the variable. If you don't, it will collapse the whitespace:

```
bash-3.2$ x=$'a\tb\nc'
bash-3.2$ cat <<< $x
a b c
bash-3.2$ cat <<< "$x"
a   b
c
```